# multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered with fixed queue size or buffer?

Tags: python, sqlite, generator, python-3.4, python-multiprocessing

I am reading data from large CSV files, processing it, and loading it into a SQLite database. Profiling suggests 80% of my time is spent on I/O and 20% is processing input to prepare it for DB insertion.  I sped up the processing step with `multiprocessing.Pool` so that the I/O code is never waiting for the next record. But, this caused serious memory problems because the I/O step could not keep up with the workers.

The following toy example illustrates my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  # 3.4.3
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def records(num=100):
    """Simulate generator getting data from large CSV files."""
    for i in range(num):
        print('Reading record {0}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(0.05)  # getting raw data is fast
        yield i

def process(rec):
    """Simulate processing of raw text into dicts."""
    print('Processing {0}'.format(rec))
    time.sleep(0.1)  # processing takes a little time
    return rec

def writer(records):
    """Simulate saving data to SQLite database."""
    for r in records:
        time.sleep(0.3)  # writing takes the longest
        print('Wrote {0}'.format(r))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = records(100)
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        writer(pool.imap_unordered(process, data, chunksize=5))
```

This code results in a backlog of records that eventually consumes all memory because I cannot persist the data to disk fast enough. Run the code and you'll notice that `Pool.imap_unordered` will consume all the data when `writer` is at the 15th record or so.  Now imagine the processing step is producing dictionaries from hundreds of millions of rows and you can see why I run out of memory. [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) in action perhaps.

What is the fix for this? I think I need some sort of buffer for `Pool.imap_unordered` that says "once there are *x* records that need insertion, stop and wait until there are less than *x* before making more."  I should be able to get some speed improvement from preparing the next record while the last one is being saved.

I tried using [`NuMap`](http://mcieslik-mctp.github.io/papy/api.html?highlight=numap#module-numap.NuMap) from the `papy` module (which I modified to work with Python 3) to do exactly this, but it wasn't faster. In fact, it was worse than running the program sequentially; `NuMap` uses two threads plus multiple processes.

Bulk import features of SQLite are probably not suited to my task because the data need substantial processing and normalization.

I have about 85G of compressed text to process. I'm open to other database technologies, but picked SQLite for ease of use and because this is a write-once read-many job in which only 3 or 4 people will use the resulting database after everything is loaded.

Comment: Using the Semaphore approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058399/3339058), I created a wrapper for an iterator to limit the number of yielded values. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bounded-iterator/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since processing is fast, but writing is slow, it sounds like your problem is
I/O-bound. Therefore there might not be much to be gained from using
multiprocessing.

However, it is possible to peel off chunks of `data`, process the chunk, and
wait until that data has been written before peeling off another chunk:

```
import itertools as IT
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = records(100)
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        chunksize = ...
        for chunk in iter(lambda: list(IT.islice(data, chunksize)), []):
            writer(pool.imap_unordered(process, chunk, chunksize=5))
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution.  It's a compromise between letting the processes get out of sync and getting some speed boost during the processing step.  It would be nice to have a `multiprocessing` function that does `imap` with some sort of buffer parameter.

Answer (score 11):

As I was working on the same problem, I figured that an effective way to prevent the pool from overloading is to use a semaphore with a generator:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Semaphore

def produce(semaphore, from_file):
    with open(from_file) as reader:
        for line in reader:
            # Reduce Semaphore by 1 or wait if 0
            semaphore.acquire()
            # Now deliver an item to the caller (pool)
            yield line

def process(item):
    result = (first_function(item),
              second_function(item),
              third_function(item))
    return result

def consume(semaphore, result):
    database_con.cur.execute("INSERT INTO ResultTable VALUES (?,?,?)", result)
    # Result is consumed, semaphore may now be increased by 1
    semaphore.release()

def main()
    global database_con
    semaphore_1 = Semaphore(1024)
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(process, produce(semaphore_1, "workfile.txt"), chunksize=128):
            consume(semaphore_1, result)
```

See also:

[K Hong - Multithreading - Semaphore objects & thread pool](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Semaphore_Objects_Thread_Pool.php)

[Lecture from Chris Terman - MIT 6.004 L21: Semaphores](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heX1d7wxuWg)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all you really need is to replace the unbounded queues underneath the `Pool` with bounded (and blocking) queues. That way, if any side gets ahead of the rest, it'll just block until they're ready.

This would be easy to do by peeking at [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l138), to subclass or monkeypatch `Pool`, something like:

```
class Pool(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def _setup_queues(self):
        self._inqueue = self._ctx.Queue(5)
        self._outqueue = self._ctx.Queue(5)
        self._quick_put = self._inqueue._writer.send
        self._quick_get = self._outqueue._reader.recv
        self._taskqueue = queue.Queue(10)
```

But that's obviously not portable (even to CPython 3.3, much less to a different Python 3 implementation).

I *think* you can do it portably in 3.4+ by providing a customized `context`, but I haven't been able to get that right, so…

Comment: This is an interesting idea that doesn't work simply in practice.  `_taskqueue` is actually assigned after `_setup_queues` is run.  Putting a max size on the queue also doesn't work due to the structure of `imap_unordered`, which will never return the generator because the queue blocks if a max size is set.

Comment: @ChrisP: Well, the first part is easy to fix, just a bit messier. The second, though, you're right. I assumed too much about the way the map functions are implemented. This would be easier to build on top of a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor; on top of `multiprocessing.Pool`, you have to basically rewrite the `map` functions from scratch on top of individual submits…

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround might be to use psutil to detect the memory usage in each process and say if more than 90% of memory are taken, than just sleep for a while.

```
while psutil.virtual_memory().percent > 75:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("process paused for 1 seconds!")
```